# Fill two datagridviews from one tableadapter

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataadapter

Is it possible to fill two DataGridView (named as Datagridview1 & Datagridview2) from one dataset < one tableadapter < 2 Different queries

```
From query 1 = DGV1 i need to fill datagridview1
From query 2 - DGV2 i need to fill datagridview2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible? Of course, that's the glory of bound datasets. Set up your 2 queries using the DataSet designer (.xsd) by right-clicking on your `TableAdapter`-->`Add Query` --> etc.

With two `DataGridViews`, you will need 2 instances of the same tableadapter (you can drag and drop from the Toolbox). Call your `FillBy` method (or whatever you named them) for each query, connecting the `DGV` data source to the correct `TableAdapter` (I just add a numerical suffix for simplicity).